# Generar el elemento "n" de una serie de manera recursiva

Tags: c++, recursión

La función es: 1,2,3,6,7,14,15,30,31... La verdad estoy casi medio dia tratando de entender recursividad y cambie tanto mi codigo que ya no se que hace

```
Cardinal Serie1(byte n){
Cardinal s;
bool b;
if (n<=3){
return n;
}else{
    if (n%2==0) {
        s=Serie1(n-1)*2;
    }else{
        s=Serie1(n-1)+1;
    }
    return Serie1(n);
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de serie es?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para explicarte un poco lo hice con javaScript, la funcion inicia con un valor, en esta serie si el numero es par se le suma uno, y si es impar se multiplica por dos, asi que en el caso inicial con 1, detecta que es impar, asi que se multiplica por dos y lo vuelve a mandar a la funcion, ahora recibe un 2, es par, suma 1, y vuelve a mandar este resultado, un 3, es impar, multiplica por 2, y vuelve....
es necesario crear una condición de escape del bucle.

```js
function cardinal(numeroInicial,n) {
 console.log(numeroInicial);
  if (n == 0) {
    return numeroInicial;
  } else {
    if (numeroInicial % 2 == 0) {
      return cardinal(numeroInicial + 1,n-1);
    } else {
      return cardinal(numeroInicial * 2,n-1);
    }
  }
}
console.log("Deseado "+cardinal(1,8));
```

Aqui esta el codigo en c++

```
int cardinal(int numeroInicial,int n){
    if (n == 0) {
      return numeroInicial;
    } else {
    if (numeroInicial % 2 == 0) {
      return cardinal(numeroInicial + 1,n-1);
    } else {
      return cardinal(numeroInicial * 2,n-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Si la pregunta es sobre [tag:c++], la respuesta no puede ser [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 1):

1,2,3,6,7,14,15,30,31, ...

La serie es ascendente y sigue las siguientes reglas:

- Si n es impar, multiplico por dos
- Si n es par, sumo uno

La recursividad es sencilla:

```
void Serie1(int n)
{
  std::cout << n << ' ';

  if( n > 1000 ) // Por parar en algún momento
    return;

  if( n % 2 == 0 )
    Serie(n+1);
  else
    Serie(n*2);
}
```